# By choosing a suitable binomial expansion of the form $(1±kx)^n$ and a suitable value of x. Find $(1.01)^{20}$ correct to 3 s.f.

Tags: binomial-theorem

I have tried replacing kx by 0.1, square rooting 0.1 and squaring 0.1, but none of these methods worked.
I don’t know where to start from. I would appreciate some assistance on this question. Thanks

Comment: What went wrong with $kx=0.01$?  How many terms of the expansion do you think you need?  MathJax hint:  to get multicharacter exponents enclose them in braces, so 1.01^{20} gives $1.01^{20}$

Comment: I think I need 3 terms of the expansion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you write out the binomial expansion
$$1.01^{20}=1^{20}+{20 \choose 1}1^{19}\cdot 0.01+{20 \choose 2}1^{18}\cdot 0.01^2 \ldots$$
You can note that the binomial increases by at most a factor $20$ while the power of $0.01$ divides by $100$.  You can bound the tail by a geometric series of ratio $\frac 15$, so the tail is less than $\frac 14$ of the last term you include.  The first two terms give $1.2$, so once a term is less than $0.01$ you can stop.

Comment: I have been able to reach to the answer. Does the ± have a role in the expansion?

Comment: No, we need the plus sign here.  I think the problem gives the $\pm$ sign because the binomial theorem is often quoted that way.  You could write up your solution.  The FAQ encourages that if you find the answer to your question and writing it down often helps find things you may have glossed over.  After some delay (48 hours?) you will be able to accept it.

Comment: That’s so true. The mistake that I made was to miss out the nCr value for the second term in the expansion.

Comment: You can't just say stop after the term is less than $0.01$, because what comes after can change the rounding of the whole sum in the worst case scenario.

Comment: @user10354138:  That is why I spent the time to bound the tail of the sum

Comment: No, because in a similar case: 4+0.14+0.0049...+... which you can guarantee a geometric-like bound on tail but can obviously change the correct rounding from 4.14 to 4.15 with arbitrarily small term, not 0.01.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer has a major flaw in thinking that, if a real number $s$ and "true" value $S$ differs by less than 0.01 then they both round to the same 2dp numbers.  But this is easily shown to be false, e.g., $1.005-10^{-12}$ and $1.005$ differs by $10^{-12}\ll 0.01$ but rounds to different numbers to 2dp (or 3sf).  In other words,

> Calculate $x$ to within error smaller than $10^{-n}$ (or half that).

and

> Calculate $x$ to n decimal places

are different problems.

So you need to keep track of both the current partial sum and potential error.  Only if you can guarantee everything in range round to the same decimal number can you stop.

So:

1. First term 1, error $0<\varepsilon<\frac14$, potential range $(1,1.25)$ is too broad.
2. Two term sum $1+\binom{20}{1}\cdot 0.01=1.20$, error $0<\varepsilon<\frac14\cdot 0.2=0.05$, potential range $(1.20,1.25)$ again too broad
3. Three term sum $1+\binom{20}{1}\cdot 0.01+\binom{20}{2}\cdot 0.01^2=1.219$, error $0<\varepsilon<\frac14\cdot 0.019=0.00475$, potential range $(1.219, 1.22375)$ falls under what is represented by 1.22 to 3sf.